# A word to describe a person who loves to perform

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word that fits the following criteria:

1. A person who loves to perform, or craves attention
2. Preferably without a negative connotation (such as *attention whore*)
3. Suitable in writing
4. Suitable for describing a person in the 17th century France

Comment: Why not use contemporary terms to describe a characteristic of the past?

Comment: Ditto josh61, is there a reason why a more modern-day expression cannot be used to describe a historical figure or a character in the past? Are you looking for a formal expression, or one that was in use in the 17th century?

Comment: 'Craves attention' _requires_ a negative denotation.

Answer (score 3):

I think [exhibitionist](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/exhibitionist) may fit your description:

> - a person who behaves in ways intended to attract attention or display his or her powers, personality, etc.

and [grandstander](http://www.wordwebonline.com/en/GRANDSTANDER) (also used in a figurative way)

> - Someone who performs with an eye to the applause from spectators in the grandstand.

Comment: Taylor Swift loves to perform. Are you accusing her of ... ?

Comment: @BlessedGeek I don't think Taylor Swift was performing  back in the 17th century.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>You can say that someone enjoys to *be in the spotlight*. 

Meaning they enjoy being the center of attention.</strike>

No longer available since the 17th century France constraint.
 Maybe go with the simple - *performer*.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the situation I'm describing is set in the 17th century France. So spotlight probably didn't exist yet. :(

Answer (score 0):

> **[artiste](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=artiste&searchmode=none)** (n.)
>   1819 in English, from **1804** as a French word, **from French *artiste***; a reborrowing of *artist*, at first in a foreign context, later used to fill the gap after the sense of artist had become limited toward the visual arts and especially painting.
>
> **Artiste**: *an admirable word (albeit somewhat Frenchified) of late applied, with nice discrimination, to every species of exhibitor, from a rope-dancer down to a mere painter or sculptor*.

something a little earlier...

> **show** (n.)
>   Meaning "display, spectacle" is first recorded **1560s**; that of "ostentatious display" is from 1713 (*showy* is from 1712).
>
> **showy** (adj.)
>   **1712**, from *show* (n.) + -y (2). Related: *Showiness*; showiness. Originally in a positive sense.
>
> **showman** (n.)
>   "one who presents shows," **1734**, from *show* (n.) + *man* (n.).
>
> **showgirl** (n.)
>   "actress whose role is decorative rather than histrionic" [OED], **1836**, from *show* (v.) + *girl*.

Perhaps this...

> **performer** (n.)
>   1580s, agent noun from perform (v.). **Theatrical sense is from 1711.**

Comment: A **show-off**.

Comment: @GEdgar but would you use this word to describe a 17th century French performer? Perhaps...

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to find a positive or neutral expression for such a person, given the characteristics you describe fit perfectly with 'narcissist', a term which is usually interpreted negatively. 'Egotist' may fit, and may be considered less negative. Otherwise, possibly, 'prima donna'.